# How to create an overlay Navigation menu on mobile screens, while having a normal navigation bar on normal screens

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, web

I want to create a custom full screen overlay navigation menu, but I am having some problems. I want the overlay to be below my transformed hamburger menu and hide everything else on the webpage.
This is the last working thing I could rollback to - https://divided7.github.io/saylus (open in mobile view). Please Help me in doing so. I am using jquery to toggle the hamburger menu's state:

Jquery

```
$("#mobile-menu").click(function () {
  $(".icon").toggleClass("close");
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("overlay")[0];
  if ($(".icon").hasClass("close")) {
    x.style.display = "block";
    $("body").addClass("modal-open");
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
    $("body").removeClass("modal-open");
  }
});
```

CSS

```
  .overlay {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    display: none;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
```

Expected result :
[Overlay covers body but is under the hamburger menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kk0aY.png)

I couldn't find an answer related to this as every code opens an overlay menu with its own closing button, but I want the closing button to remain fixed and on top of the overlay.

Comment: you should add some code so we can pinpoint were you're problem is. Reading your comment, your just looking for setting the right z-index on the elements

Comment: Its not  a problem, I just want to know how I can go about displaying an overlay on clicking the navbar menu in mobile view. I want the overlay to cover the whole screen and the close button to be on top of it, I have just been able to change the menu from hamburger icon to close icon yet, hence, I dont  have the related code, but I think the screenshot and the webpage linked are pretty self explanatory.

Comment: what have you tried so far? it's a simple show/hide of a absolute or fixed positioned div with a z-index higher than your content and lower then your header... this you can find all over the inet

Comment: thanks for the answer @Rmaxx , I tried what you asked me to do, hiding the body(except the navbar on clicking the menu button), but when I display the body again, everything seems to be pretty weirdly placed, and the navbar button disappears to. I cant explain it by typing it out, please check the link again.
Also, I am adding the jquery code I am using to hide and show the body

Comment: dont hide the body, simply place a white div containing the menu on top of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the basics:

```js
$('.toggle').on('click',function(){
  $('body').toggleClass('active');
})
```

```css
body{ background:#eee; padding:0; margin:0; overflow:auto;}

body.active{
  overflow:hidden;
}
.header{ 
  position:fixed;
  z-index:10;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  padding:10px;
  width:100%;
  height:30px;
  background:#000; 
  color:#fff;
  }

.overlay{
  position:fixed;
  display:none;
  z-index:5;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  background-color:#333;
  color:#fff;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}

body.active .overlay{
  display:block;
  }

.menu{
   display:flex;
   align-items:center;
   width:100%;
   height:100%;
   justify-content:center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  
<body>
<div class="header"><button class="toggle">menu</button></div>
<div class="overlay">
  <div class="menu">menu</div>
</div>
lorem ipsum<br/>
lorem ipsum<br/>
lorem ipsum<br/>
lorem ipsum<br/>lorem ipsum<br/>
lorem ipsum<br/>
lorem ipsum<br/>
lorem ipsum<br/>lorem ipsum<br/>
lorem ipsum<br/>
lorem ipsum<br/>
lorem ipsum<br/>lorem ipsum<br/>
lorem ipsum<br/>
lorem ipsum<br/>
lorem ipsum<br/>lorem ipsum<br/>
lorem ipsum<br/>
lorem ipsum<br/>
lorem ipsum<br/>lorem ipsum<br/>
lorem ipsum<br/>
lorem ipsum<br/>
lorem ipsum<br/>lorem ipsum<br/>
lorem ipsum<br/>
lorem ipsum<br/>
lorem ipsum<br/>lorem ipsum<br/>
lorem ipsum<br/>
lorem ipsum<br/>
lorem ipsum<br/>lorem ipsum<br/>
lorem ipsum<br/>
lorem ipsum<br/>
lorem ipsum<br/>lorem ipsum<br/>
lorem ipsum<br/>
lorem ipsum<br/>
lorem ipsum<br/>lorem ipsum<br/>
lorem ipsum<br/>
lorem ipsum<br/>
lorem ipsum<br/>lorem ipsum<br/>
lorem ipsum<br/>
lorem ipsum<br/>
lorem ipsum<br/>lorem ipsum<br/>
lorem ipsum<br/>
lorem ipsum<br/>
lorem ipsum<br/>lorem ipsum<br/>
lorem ipsum<br/>
lorem ipsum<br/>
lorem ipsum<br/>
</body>
```